# Web scraping 40+ websites in search of opportunities in python

Tags: python, dataframe, web, nlp, screen-scraping

I am trying to automate the task of searching for opportunities (tenders) in 40+ websites, for a company. The opportunities are usually displayed in table format. They have a title, date published, and a clickable link that takes you to a detailed description of what the opportunity is.
One website example is:
http://www.eib.org/en/about/procurement/index.htm

The goal would be to retrieve the new opportunities that are posted everyday and that fit specific criteria. So I need to look at specific keywords within the opportunities' title. These keywords are the fields and regions in which the company had previous experience.

My question is: After I extract these tables, with the tenders' titles, in a dataframe format,  how do I search for the right opportunities and sort them by relevance (given a list of keywords)? Do I use NLP in this case and turn the words in the titles into binary code (0s and 1s)? Or are there other simpler methods I should be looking at?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

To sort the tenders by relevance, you need define the relevance.
In this case you could count the number of occurrence of your keywords in the tender and this would be your relevance score. You can then only keep the ones that have at least one appearing keyword.
This is a first try, you can improve this by adding keywords, or assign a higher score if the keyword is in the title rather than in the detailed description...

The task you might be trying to solve here is information retrieval:  rank documents (the tenders) given their relevance to a query (your keyword).
So then you can use weighing schemes like Tf-Idf or BM25, etc... But it depends on your needs, maybe counting the keyword is more than enough !

Comment: Oh wow, you just opened a whole new pandora box for me ( I am fairly new to python). Thank you so much for your insightful comment. Wasn't aware of Tf-Idf or BM25! Would these functions be able to parse both PDFs and webpages ? (the tenders sometimes open up in PDF format) Which one is the easiest to implement? (By the way, I have a list of keywords which the company gave me, which include geographies in which they are most active, such as MENA, North Africa etc, and sectors in which they operate such as energy and logistics) I thank you again for taking the time to respond!

Comment: The ideas I proposed all rely on having a preprocessed document in text format. So if you have PDF or any other non txt data you should first somehow convert them to txt (which is not trivial either, if you need like OCR or to parse pdf files).
Before falling down a rabbit hole, please try to just count the keywords ! (tf-idf is implemented in SKLearn but you can do it by hand if you understand what is does).